# Avoid button getting called with space/enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some buttons that can be clicked either by mouse or key presses. Then I have a function called by space-key.

The problem is that when one of the buttons has been clicked with mouse, it seems the button gets selected (focussed) and when the space-key (and enter-key) gets pressed afterwards, the browser calls the selected (focussed) button instead of the intended function for the space key.

I've found a solution long time ago so I know there is a solution but can't remember.

Edit: This is not inside a form.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the spacebar for your form, you can do an event.preventDefaut() on keypress for the spacebar.

```
$(yourbuttonelements).keydown(function(e) {
    var kc = e.keyCode; 
    if (kc === 32){
    e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to bypass the `default` event on a `keypress`, you need to first delegate a '`keypress`' or related `event` and then check for `event.which` to find the corresponding key `pressed` and if it matches with what you want to prevent, you can either do `return false;` or do `event.preventDefault();`

Example :

```
$('button').on('keypress',function(e)
{
  if(e.which == 32)  // 32 -> represents the keycode of space bar
      e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault() didn't work though I found a solution.
As mentioned, the problem was the button got focussed when clicked, so I used blur() for the button.

```
document.getElementById(id).blur();
```